# deleting lines in between two patterns on notepad++ regex

Tags: notepad++

```
(?<=] = {)(.*\n?)(?=\},)
```

That is what I've come up with, I'm new to this regular expression. What I want to do is to delete texts/lines after "] = {" and before "},"

the problem is, lots of my lines repeat and whenever I search '(?<=] = {)(.*\n?)(?=},)' It highlights the topmost "] = {" and the bottom-most "},". I want it to highlight the 'NEXT' "},". Sorry if I couldn't make myself clearer. English is not my native language. TY!

Here's 0.01% of the text file that I need to edit.

```
[502] = {
    unidentifiedDescriptionName = {
        "A potion made from grinded Red and Yellow Herbs that restores ^000088about 105 HP^000000.",
        "^ffffff_^000000",
        "Weight: ^77777710^000000"
    },
    identifiedDisplayName = "Orange Potion",
    identifiedResourceName = "주홍포션",
    identifiedDescriptionName = {
        "A potion made from grinded Red and Yellow Herbs that restores ^000088about 105 HP^000000.",
        "^ffffff_^000000",
        "Weight: ^77777710^000000"
    },
    slotCount = 0,
    ClassNum = 0
},
[503] = {
    unidentifiedDescriptionName = {
        "A potion made from grinded Yellow Herbs that restores about ^000088175 HP^000000.",
        "^ffffff_^000000",
        "Weight: ^77777713^000000"
    },
    identifiedDisplayName = "Yellow Potion",
    identifiedResourceName = "노란포션",
    identifiedDescriptionName = {
        "A potion made from grinded Yellow Herbs that restores about ^000088175 HP^000000.",
        "^ffffff_^000000",
        "Weight: ^77777713^000000"
    },
    slotCount = 0,
    ClassNum = 0
},
```

I need to delete lines from the [502] = { to the }, before the 'identifieddisplayname'.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance! This is my first post! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close:

Find what: `(?<=] = {)(.*?)(?=\},)`
Replace with: `NOTHING`

Make sure you have checked `. matches newline`

Comment: I'd vote up if I had the reputation! Thanks my friend!

Comment: You could add a little explanation, maybe just a link to http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html and the keywords "regexp lazy quantifier".